# WPF UI to CLR Connectivity

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, clr

I have a CLR object called Restaurant

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int _id {get; set;}
    public string _name {get; set;}
    public Restaurant()
    {}
}
```

I also have a custom UI element created called RestaurantViewer. My question is, Is there a way to connect them together as in When i instantiate a RestaurantViewer it instantiates a Restaurant object too?

Comment: You want `Restaurant` to be DataContext of `RestaurantViewer`?

Comment: Make a property of the Restaurant object in your RestaurantViewer class and create a new instance in the constructor. Otherwise use constructor injection.